# PowerShell regex export match contents

Tags: regex, powershell

I am learning regex and am trying to get a better understanding by using a text file with the value $100,000 in it. What I am trying to do is to search the text file for the string "$100,000" and if it is there export the value out into a new CSV. this is what I'm using so far.

```
      [io.file]::readalltext("c:\utilities\notes_$datetime.txt") -match("[$][0-9][0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9][0-9]") | Out-File C:\utilities\amount.txt -Encoding ascii -Force
```

Which returns true. Can someone point me in the right direction as to grabbing the string value that it finds into a new CSV?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the file into a single string, not an array of lines, so you should use the `Select-String -AllMatches` instead of the `-match` operator:

```
[IO.File]::ReadAllText("c:\utilities\notes_$datetime.txt") |
  Select-String '\$\d{3},\d{3}' -AllMatches |
  % { $_.Matches.Groups.Value } |
  Out-File C:\utilities\amount.txt -Encoding ascii -Force
```

As a side note, using `Get-Content -Raw` would be slightly more PoSh than using .Net methods, although .Net methods provide better performance.

```
Get-Content "c:\utilities\notes_$datetime.txt" -Raw |
  Select-String '\$\d{3},\d{3}' -AllMatches |
  % { $_.Matches.Groups.Value } |
  Out-File C:\utilities\amount.txt -Encoding ascii -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use **[regex]::match** for that:

```
$x = 'text bla $100,000 text text'
[regex]::Match($x,"\$[\d]{3},[\d]{3}").Groups[0].Value
```

I also changed the expression a little bit ($ followed by 3 numbers, followed by a "," and another 3 numbers).

So your script could look like this:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content "c:\utilities\notes_$datetime.txt"    
[regex]::Match($fileContent,"\$[\d]{3},[\d]{3}").Groups[0].Value | Out-File C:\utilities\amount.txt -Encoding ascii -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the Select-String cmdlet - far easier:

```
Select-String .\infile.csv -pattern '\$[\d]{3},[\d]{3}' | Select Line | Out-File outfile.txt
```

You can then process multiple files like so:

```
Get-Childitem *.csv | Select-String -pattern '\$[\d]{3},[\d]{3}' | Select Line | Out-File outfile.txt
```

The Select-String has the following properties:

Line - the line where the regex found a match

LineNumber - the line number in the file where the match was found

Filename - the name of the file the match was found in